# Tornado - '_xsrf' argument missing from POST

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

As can be seen in the following code, I have a `GET` for registration, that delegates its work to `POST`.

```
class RegistrationHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        s = """
          <h1>Register</h1>
              <form method="post" action="/register">
                  <div>
                      <label>User</label>
                      <input name="user_name" value="test@test.com"/>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                      <label>password</label>
                      <input name="password" type="password"/>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                  </div>
              </form>
        """
        self.write(s)

    @log_exception()
    def post(self):
        user_name = self.request.arguments['user_name']
        password = self.request.arguments['password']
        log.debug('Registering user with credentials %r' % (user_name, password))
        with sa_session() as db_session:
            User.register(user_name, password, db_session)
```

When I access the URL from my web browser, I get a registration form, after submitting which I get "403: Forbidden".

Console log:

```
2012-10-15 11:27:42,482 - __main__ - DEBUG - Starting server on port 8080
2012-10-15 11:27:49,377 - root - INFO - 304 GET /register (127.0.0.1) 0.78ms
2012-10-15 11:27:53,143 - root - WARNING - 403 POST /register (127.0.0.1): '_xsrf' argument missing from POST
2012-10-15 11:27:53,144 - root - WARNING - 403 POST /register (127.0.0.1) 1.05ms
```

What does this error mean and how do I correct it? Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I imagine you have Cross-site request forgery  cookies enabled in your settings 
(by default it is on).

[Tornado's XSRF is here](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-protection)

To fix this turn it off in your settings:

```
settings = {
    "xsrf_cookies": False,
}
```

Note: Normally you dont want to turn this off and normally you'd be generating HTML in a template like this: Please note the xsrf bit which adds the XSRF cookie.

```
 <form method="post" action="/register">
     <input name="user_name" value="test@test.com"/>
     <input name="password" type="password"/>
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
{% raw xsrf_form_html() %}
 </form>
```

---EDIT following comments---
Instead of:

```
  def get(self):
        loader = template.Loader("resources")
        page_contents = loader.load('register_page.html').generate()
        self.write(page_contents)
```

Do:

```
  def get(self):
     self.render("../resources/register_page.html")
```

or better:

```
  def get(self):
     self.render("register_page.html")
```

(and put it in your templates directory)

Comment: It raises an error that name `xsrf_form_html()` is not defined. Do I need some import? If yes, how do I add it in my template?

Comment: You dont need any special imports. Note that xsrf_form_html() will only work in a Template. The code you posted above is not a template.

Comment: Here's my Python code - https://www.refheap.com/paste/5955, and here's my template - https://www.refheap.com/paste/5956.

Comment: The error message reads `NameError: global name 'xsrf_form_html' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here.
After digging a while into the code I checked the tornado built-in function which makes that check:

```
def check_xsrf_cookie(self):
    """Verifies that the ``_xsrf`` cookie matches the ``_xsrf`` argument.

    To prevent cross-site request forgery, we set an ``_xsrf``
    cookie and include the same value as a non-cookie
    field with all ``POST`` requests. If the two do not match, we
    reject the form submission as a potential forgery.

    The ``_xsrf`` value may be set as either a form field named ``_xsrf``
    or in a custom HTTP header named ``X-XSRFToken`` or ``X-CSRFToken``
    (the latter is accepted for compatibility with Django).

    See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

    Prior to release 1.1.1, this check was ignored if the HTTP header
    ``X-Requested-With: XMLHTTPRequest`` was present.  This exception
    has been shown to be insecure and has been removed.  For more
    information please see
    http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2011/feb/08/security/
    http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails

    .. versionchanged:: 3.2.2
       Added support for cookie version 2.  Both versions 1 and 2 are
       supported.
    """
    token = (self.get_argument("_xsrf", None) or
             self.request.headers.get("X-Xsrftoken") or
             self.request.headers.get("X-Csrftoken"))
    if not token:
        raise HTTPError(403, "'_xsrf' argument missing from POST")
    _, token, _ = self._decode_xsrf_token(token)
    _, expected_token, _ = self._get_raw_xsrf_token()
    if not token:
        raise HTTPError(403, "'_xsrf' argument has invalid format")
    if not _time_independent_equals(utf8(token), utf8(expected_token)):
        raise HTTPError(403, "XSRF cookie does not match POST argument")
```

As you can read into the method definition:

> The `_xsrf` value may be set as either a form field named `_xsrf`
> or in a custom HTTP header named `X-XSRFToken` or `X-CSRFToken`

Therefore I tried setting an HTTP header named `X-CSRFToken`. The following is the ajax definition:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.my_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(body),
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', getCookie('_xsrf'));},
});
```

Lastly, we need to define the function `getCookie` which is responsible for retrieving the right CSRF-token. The definition of this function has been taken directly from the Tornado [CSRF documentation](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-protection):

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var r = document.cookie.match("\\b" + name + "=([^;]*)\\b");
    return r ? r[1] : undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a conflict :
how do you make `get` and in the form you put `method="post"` ? this why there is `error 403`

if you use `get`, then you will not need an `xsrf` protection. else, you add it after the form declaration as

```
<form method="post" action="/register">
{% raw xsrf_form_html() %} # the 'raw' word is to force escape to be desactivated (it is by default activated)
```

so the xsrf you'll find it a hidden tag in your rendered html.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it changing the form method in the HTML file:
`<form method="post" action="/register">`
for
`<form method="POST" action="/register`